# Show Timer while method is processing C#

Tags: c#

I want to display the time elapsing in seconds while a method is processing and returns its response. Probably it will be done with Tasks or Threads but i am not really able to achieve it.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

```
public function()
{
    while(wait for getAllInformation() function is processing)
    {
        Console.Write("Elapsed time... "+ some timer which shows time in seconds);
    }
}
```

Comment: you should do the timing in separate task. completely separate from function. part of the code showing and updating time should not be mixed with `function` at all. they are completely separate things. just before starting function you start timer, and after function is completed, you should stop timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that:

```
public async Task MyMehod()
{
            Task<IEnumerable<int>> infoGetTask = GetAllInformation();

            Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            while (!infoGetTask.IsCompleted)
            {
                Console.Write($"Elapsed time... {Math.Round(stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds, 0)}");
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }

            foreach (int e in infoGetTask.Result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<int>> GetAllInformation()
        {
            await Task.Delay(3000);

            return new int[3] { 1, 2, 3 };
        }
```

Note that for simplicity I'm only checking for IsCompleted but there are two other possible flags that can/should be checked.

Comment: @user3728843 I'm glad it helped you! I will appreciate it if you could mark my answer as accepted nor upvote (:

Answer (score 2):

You should use Microsoft' Reactive Framework for this. Then you can simply do this:

```
public int GetAllInformationWithTimer()
{
    using (Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))
        .Subscribe(x => 
            Console.WriteLine("Elapsed Time: {0} seconds", x + 1)))
    {
        return GetAllInformation();
    }   
}
```

Just NuGet "System.Reactive" to get the library you need.

Comment: Although the below solution worked, but would also explore this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user3728843 - The Reactive Framework is extremely powerful. I use it for almost anything that Tasks and events can do - and it does so much more.